# Remove child objects using linq

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Trying to remove several deep child objects from a parent object.

It's a survey and I'm trying to remove the QuestionType object (But keep the QuestionType key) before it gets added to the database.

The tree is like this:

Survey.SectionList.Section.QuestionList.Question.QuestionType

I want it like this:

Survey.SectionList.Section.QuestionList.Question

I'm importing the Survey object from an XML file that was exported by an other instance of the system. Part of that export is the QuestionType. When I import the survey and shove it into a Survey object and then follow it with a db.Add then the QuestionType records are being added instead of just referencing the existing ones.

(I think) I know I could throw it all in a series of foreach loops to get down to the Questions layer but that seems so old school.

Thanks in advance for your patience with this toddler mind.

Comment: What is your question? Where is your code?

Comment: maybe something like `db.Entry(Survey.SectionList.QuestionList.Question).State = EntityState.Detached;` before you call `db.Add()`

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the questions, then modify them:

given: `List<Survey> surveyList`

```
List<Question> questions = surveyList.SelectMany(s => s.SectionList)
                .SelectMany(sl => sl.Section)
                .SelectMany(sct => sct.QuestionList)
                .SelectMany(ql => ql.Question).ToList();

foreach(Question q in questions)
    q.QuestionType = null;
```

Or you can get even more fancy by using an "linq-to-objects update":

```
surveyList.SelectMany(s => s.SectionList)
                .SelectMany(sl => sl.Section)
                .SelectMany(sct => sct.QuestionList)
                .SelectMany(ql => ql.Question)
                .Select(q =>
                    {
                        q.QuestionType = null;
                        return q;
                    }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override `SaveChanges` in the `DbContext` class and set the state of `QuestionType` objects to `UnChanged`:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    var oc = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext;
    oc.DetectChanges();
    foreach (var ent in oc.ObjectStateManager
                          .GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added)
                          .Select(e => e.Entity)
                          .OfType<QuestionType>())
    {
        oc.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(ent, EntityState.Unchanged);
    }
    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

By setting the state to `UnChanged` the associations between `Question` and `QuestionType` will stay intact, but now only the foreign key values will be saved, not the `QuestionType`s.

Comment: I've been on this website for going on a decade and I still don't have the 15 respect points needed for an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

You guys are so awesome. Thanks for the variety of real answers from my basically crappy post.

This is whut I finally got working yesterday so I could move forward. However, after I add the unit tests I'm going to refactor to one of your responses.

```
private Survey PrepSurveyForAdd(Survey survey)
{
  //Loop through the sections
  foreach (SurveySection ss in survey.SurveySections)
  {
    foreach (SectionQuestion sq in ss.Section.SectionQuestions)
    {
      sq.Question.QuestionType = null;

    }
  }
  return survey;
}
```

The reason I'm not staying with that, and why I posted originally, was because I was not only having problems referencing down the tree but because I wanted to learn some more about Linq with a real world, it matters to me, example.